# Creating circular association with three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 3 base models as shoe, color, and size.

Shoes have many colors and many sizes, but for each color they have available_sizes.

To be able to perform that I should look at both shoe_id and color_id and fetch size_ids according to them on a triple joint model.

Opposite condition (available_colors) exists as well.

Then, our models will be like that:

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :colors, through: :stocks
  has_many :sizes, through: :stocks
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :shoes, through: :stocks
end

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stocks
  has_many :shoes, through: :stocks
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shoe
  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :size
end
```

What I want though, querying something like `shoe.sizes.availabe_colors` or `shoe.colors.available_sizes`.

How should I implement associations to make all shoe, color, and size models play well together?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right, your wanting to find all of the available sizes for a particular shoe given a specific color. In other words, what sizes are in stock for a Red shoe "A".

Since Stock is the one joining all of the other models, you'll want to do your querying on it. First you can start with getting the stocks for a specific shoe, then cutting down the stocks to a specific color, then asking it for the unique sizes

```
Shoe.find(shoe_id).stocks.where(:color_id => color_id).sizes.uniq
```

To clean this up, make it an instance method in `Shoe`

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def available_sizes_for_color(color_id)
    stocks.where(:color_id => color_id).sizes.uniq
  end
end

Shoe.find(shoe_id).available_sizes_for_color(color_id)
```

And vice versa for finding colors by size.

An alternative using the Stock model:

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def sizes(shoe_id, color_id)
      Shoe.find(shoe_id).stocks.where(:color_id => color_id).sizes.uniq
    end
  end
end

Stock.sizes(shoe_id, color_id)
```

And finally, using the Size model:

```
class Size
  class << self
    def find_all_by_shoe_and_color(shoe_id, color_id)
      joins(:stock => [:shoe, :color]).where('shoes.id = ? AND colors.id = ?', size_id, color_id)
    end
  end
end

Size.find_all_by_shoe_and_color(shoe_id, color_id)
```

Comment: Alright, I was hoping to resolve this in an association-y way but you have shown me that a couple of scopes could do the magic as well. I will try to implement and see that if it fits for all of the situation. Thank you.